# Modify trpc error before sending the response

Tags: javascript, typescript, trpc

The [documentation](https://trpc.io/docs/server/error-handling#handling-errors) says "Here you can handle or change errors.". It then continues without any mention on how to actually do this.

Searching for how to do this did not yield any results so I'm trying my luck here.

Comment: @Unmitigated Yes, I did try `opts.error = new TRPCError({message: 'changed error',code: 'INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR',})` and `opts.error.message="changed"` but that did not change the error returned by the server.

Comment: Were you able to figure out a new solution?